# Camel multicast - transaction boundary

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a question about Apache Camel. I wasn't able to find whether the multicast  is transacted. If it is transacted, how the transactions are implemented? what is the transaction boundary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is transacted, the boundary is the whole route, as if you weren't using multicast. You can see this discussion thread for more details: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Transaction-and-Multicast-or-to-AND-to-td476483.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken